# Capture a screen shot before a Share Extension's view appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, swift2

I'm creating a share extension that currently captures web content via javascript, and a resulting `NSDictionary [NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey]`. That's all working great.

The next phase of my implementation is to get a screen shot of the `web view` of the page in `Safari` that the user is on.

Does anyone know if there's a pattern where taking a screen shot of the web page prior to the view that's loading w/the extension?  Clearly `viewWillAppear` won't work, but I'll past the code I have none the less:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *screenShotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.imageView.image = screenShotImage;

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

Comment: How about `[self.view.window.screen snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO]`?

Comment: This yields the same results for the current view (which is the extension view I'm calling it from).. I am examining the comments on UIView (UISnapshotting) in the UIView.h   I'm thinking I need to gain access to the last screenshot taken by iOS itself.   The comment on *Creating snapshots from existing snapshots. Thanks for the post anyway :)

Comment: How about running `[[UIScreen mainScreen] snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO]` in your view controller’s `initWithCoder:` method (assuming you’re using nibs or storyboards), then saving the result in a property?

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: what happens? Is `initWithCoder:` never called? Or is the capture blank?

Comment: initWithCoder faithfully gets called first but the image thats taken is a screenshot of the self view, not the Safari window that was present prior.    Theres got to be a way.

Comment: If you make a breakpoint at the place where you’re capturing the screenshot and you can’t see Safari, then your method is being called too late and your only other chance would be to call the screenshot in `+alloc`. Otherwise, Apple is playing a trick on you and there’s nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Of course it is.   Have you done what my question asks before?

Comment: I haven’t done this before. However, one solution would be to have the JS add a hash to the URL that links to a website that the JS uploaded the DOM tree to.

Comment: Yep.   I've got JS wired up also and getting the URL for this Use case.   Maybe the thing to do is pass the URL into my own UIWebView and snapshot that.

Comment: That seems to be the best idea. I was just thinking about the other way of doing it so the user’s input and changes are reflected in the screenshot.

Comment: The end solution was to put in a UIWebView and capture a portion of that view after it finished loading.